# El ancho de una barra de navegación desborde o salga de un DIV (abarque el ancho de pantalla)

Tags: div, nav

buenos días, tengo una barra de vacacional dentro de un DIV, lo que necesito es que la barra abarque el ancho de la pantalla, pero no sale del DIV donde esta, lo hice con unos H1 y H2 y si funciono pero no con la NAV, les paso el código.

La barra tiene que estar dentro de el DIV Agrupar en todo momento.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="agrupar.css" >
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="agrupar">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>PRINCIPAL</a></li>
                    <li><a>FOTOS</a></li>
                    <li><a>VIDEOS</a></li>
                    <li><a>CONTACTO</a></li>
                    <li><a>ACORTADOR</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
#agrupar {
    width:950px;
    margin:-60px auto;
}


nav {
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#e24f62;
    padding:10px;
    border-top:3px solid #9b111e;
    border-bottom:3px solid #9b111e;    
    content:" ";
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
}
```

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola @Vagabundo05, ¿quisiste decir _"...pero no sale del DIV donde esta..."_ o por el contrario, deseas que salga del **DIV**?

Comment: No se entiende la duda amigo trata de ser más claro

Comment: Esta dentro del DIV, pero quiero que se desborde o salga de el.

Comment: @Vagabundo05, Voy a modificar algo la respuesta en función de lo que has comentado, pero agrégalo a tu pregunta para que se entienda mejor. Creo que quisiste decir que se saliera del elemento `nav` la lista desordenada, ¿cierto?

Comment: No tiene sentido, si deseas que lo supere o desborde no es mejor quitar ese contenedor? Y así que el nav que es bloque tome su ancho natural?

Comment: @Aprendiz tiene razón. Tiene sentido y sugiero que sigas su recomendación, a menos que desees hacer otra cosa. De allí, la importancia de que lo aclares en tu pregunta.

Comment: Lo entiendo, de hecho antes estaba así, pero por "practicidad se acordó" que tiene que ir dentro para que al verse en diferentes ancho de monitor no afecte el posicionamiento de otros elementos.

Comment: @Vagabundo05, Ok. Trata de colocar una imagen de cómo quieres que se vea.

Answer (score 1):

> **IMPORTANTE:** Lea los comentarios puestos en el código de esta publicación.

La mejor forma de lograr que cubra todo el ancho disponible es que no se defina su anchura, ya que como el elemento `nav` es un elemento de bloque lo hace de forma natural.

**Partiendo del siguiente fragmento:**

```css
nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #e24f62;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 3px solid #9b111e;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #9b111e;

  /* Esta propiedad solamente tiene sentido en los
     pseudos elemento «::before» y «::after» */
  content: " ";

  /* Esta propiedad no tiene sentido acá, ya que el elemento
     «nav» no es una lista desordenada: */
  list-style: none;

  /* Debes eliminar esta propiedad, no es necesaria. El
     elemento «nav» es un elemento de bloque, por lo tanto,
     cubre todo el ancho de la pantalla de forma natural */
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Recomendación**

Para lograr el efecto deseado debes realizar el siguiente cambio:

- Eliminar la propiedad `content` de la regla `nav {}` ya que el elemento no es un elemento de bloque.
- Eliminar `width: 100%`, ya que no es necesaria, dado que es un elemento de bloque y los elementos de bloque cubren todo el ancho disponible.

Por lo tanto, se podrían realizar los siguientes cambios:

```css
nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #e24f62;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 3px solid #9b111e;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #9b111e;
  color: white;
}
```

Y para eliminar las viñetas de las listas desordenadas podrías implementarlo así:

```css
nav {
  list-style: none;
}
```

#### Reproducción de ejemplo

Entendiendo lo anteriormente expuesto podemos observar el ejemplo que se reproduce a continuación:

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  
}

/* Cambios sin las propiedades
   «content», «width» y «list-style».*/
nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #e24f62;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 3px solid #9b111e;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #9b111e;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  /* Quitar la viñeta a la lista desordenada */
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="agrupar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a>PRINCIPAL</a></li>
      <li><a>FOTOS</a></li>
      <li><a>VIDEOS</a></li>
      <li><a>CONTACTO</a></li>
      <li><a>ACORTADOR</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```